# How do I translate this SQL to ActiveRecord correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to select `items` that belong to a product. They have to be distinct on `items.condition`. Here's the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (items.condition) items.id, items.condition, items.price, products.name
FROM products
INNER JOIN items ON products.id = items.product_id
WHERE products.id = 1
ORDER BY items.condition, items.price, products.name;
```

I tried this, but I'm getting `StatementInvalid` error. I'm using Rails 4.

```
product = Product.find(1)
product.items.select("DISTINCT ON(items.condition) items.id, products.*, items.*").order('items.condition, items.price, products.name')
```

Error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "products"
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON(items.condition) items.id, products.*, it...
                                                      ^
: SELECT DISTINCT ON(items.condition) items.id, products.*, items.* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."product_id" = $1  ORDER BY items.condition, items.price, products.name
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "products"
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON(items.condition) items.id, products.*, it...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this(Not tested)

```
Product.joins(:items).select("DISTINCT(items.condition), items.id, products.*").order('items.condition, items.price, products.name')
```

Comment: Thanks. But that uses the Product class. I need this for a single product. So something like `Product.find(1).joins...`?

Comment: That is not going to work because joins cannot be called on a product object. Try the reverse. `Product.joins().find(1)`

Comment: OK. Thanks. Is there a way to turn this into a instance method? So instead of calling on `Product`, we can call it on an instance of `Product`?